# Where store computed values in redux

Tags: redux

What do you advice to where to store computed values? Example: API serves to me `product` property as union of `1 | 2 | 3`. In app this is interpreted as `normal | premium | platinum`. When user changes this, to API goes as `1 | 2 | 3`. What is the most reliable way to store? As original API values (and use selectors or similar and compute) or values which I use on front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying `normal | premium | platinum` as a visual representation of the actual numeric API values. Since you will need the numeric values again, translating them back and forth bears the risk of values of introducing errors, e.g. when a new state is added by another developer.

My recommendation is: Internally work with the numeric values. If it comes to showing them to the user, use a selector like `selectNameForProduct` that will give you the strings. Then you have only one place where you need to deal with an maintain the strings.